# Ubuntu 15.10 takes long time to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 15.10, plymouth

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 in dual boot with Windows 10. Since the installation, Ubuntu is taking about 1 minute to boot. Before the login  screen the plymouth boot splash screen does not show up. Instead a black screen is displayed for about 20 seconds. So I figured it may be the problem but I am just guessing.

What I did was :

1. Ran *s**ystemd-analyze blame***. Found the plymouth quit-wait service taking 20 secs. So masked it by running **systemctl mask plymouth-quit-wait.service**.
2. However no improvement in boot time.Although the log does not show the   plymouth-quit-wait.service it is taking the same amount of time. 
   Ran **systemctl mask plymouth-quit-wait.service** again. This is the file here http://pastebin.com/QhBrGt2x
3. Also ran the bootup-repair utility but no help.Boot time is the same. This is the file generated by it here http://paste.ubuntu.com/15381960/

**Note:** I have 8 GB RAM and a HDD. My Windows 10 also takes similar time to boot. I also installed the Gnome-Desktop utility

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think the boot time is wrong, or a problem ? Also, do you have an nvidia graphics card ?  As far as I know, nvidia and plymouth don't play nicely together.

Comment: @hatterman I have AMD R7 M265 on laptop for which no drivers have been installed. Should I install them? I thought Ubuntu boots fast but truly I have no idea. Also the black screen instead of plymouth made me think something was wrong.

Comment: Fast is in the eye of the beholder. 1 minute is fast compared to 2. Try not to get too obsessed with boot speeds. If it really is an issue, replace your HDD with SSD and/or suspend instead of shutting down. For AMD cards there is the proprietary driver fglxr and the open source driver radeon. Do a search on here for more info. I dont do any gaming so I always make sure my laptops have intel graphics. For me it just works. OpenGL and video decoding out of the box.

Comment: advice noted @hatterman

Answer (score 1):

I had a boot time of about 7:30 minutes. Ubuntu 15.10 using Lubuntu desktop on my Dell Inspirion 15 (3521) Laptop. I ran:

```
sudo systemd-analyze && systemd-analyze blame
```

Then I found the culprit and masked the service with

```
sudo systemctl mask <SERVIVE NAME>.
```

Boot is still a little slow but better 3:13 min. Shaved off 4 minutes of wait time. Still working on other services.

**Update:** After booting, I also noticed that the system looked for a swap partition. I commented it out in `/etc/fstab`. Now the boot time is 1:01 min. Oh, I am using Kodibuntu upgraded with Lubuntu desktop.